# ARC and OpenGl ES 2.0 : old shapes are rendering in a new scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble with OpenGL ES 2.0 and automatic-ref-couting (arc).

When I launch a Scene (a background, two pawns and some cases) it follows this process :

1/ Creating a context

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
```

2/ Compiling the shaders

3/ Setting up the framebuffer

```
GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);   
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
```

4/ Clearing the color before each render

```
glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

5/ render all the shapes

The first launch, everything is OK and renders correctly.
Then I navigate to the menu, launch another level, all the 1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5/ are processed again in order to generate the new level. 
The problem is that my old pawns and cases are visible, blinking/clipping/transparent.

**EDIT** : I'm using arc, and the controller don't release my old scene, event if I set the it to nil, so I redirect my tags to an arc problem.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sound like an ARC problem.  It sounds like you aren't tearing down / removing the old scene correctly.

While ARC takes care of memory management automatically, it won't automatically disconnect stuff from object graphs merely because your local strong reference goes away (unless that object graph has a weak reference).

So, what is likely happening is that you:

- create the OpenGL goop
- shove it into the render tree, causing it to be retained
- nil out your local reference

At that point, the render tree still has a strong -- a retained -- reference that isn't going to go away unless you explicitly remove it.

Comment: You're absoluterly right: I've tried to set to nil the local reference, pause the timer making the objects rendering and remove the scene from the superview, but the dealloc method is never called. But I don't find the good way to remove the scene from the render tree ?